# Iterating through large files without for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two large files with 16000+ entries that I want to iterate through, compare four variables from them and perform some calculations when there is a match. These files represent the same set of models but contain somewhat different output, thus all of the models from file 1 have a match in file 2.

File 1 and file 2 are tables where each column has a header. For instance, file 1 is

| # | a1 | b1 | c1 | d1 | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 33 | 22.1 | 1e20 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 56 | 85.6 | 2e30 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And file 2 is

| # | a2 | b2 | c2 | d2 | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 98 | 34.8 | 3e15 | 40 |
| 2 | 12 | 22 | 10.2 | 5e10 | 20 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Essentially, a1, b1, c1, d1 and a2, b2, c2, d2 represent the same values/models but in a different order. I want to match them and create a new table that will look like this:

| # | a | b | c | d | length | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Intuitively, I'd create two for loops of this type:

```py
for i in range(len(file1)):
       for j in range(len(file2)):  
           if a1[i] == a2[j] and b1[i]==b2[j] and c1[i]==c2[j] and d1[i]==d2[j]:
              #some calculations on age and length
```

I wonder if there is a more robust way that would avoid having a nested for loop.

UPD: I forgot to mention that I need to match the a, b, c, d terms because they describe the model parameters.

Comment: Can you show samples of the files and their contents?

Comment: Are the data sorted somehow, or do you really need to check each row of `file1` with each row of `file2`?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are working with? Files don't have a ``len``, nor are they indexable. Is this text or binary data? What are ``a1``, ``a2``, ``b1``, …?

Answer (score 1):

if your goal is to reduce nested loop but you are ok with still iterating over each file, would this work for your case?

```
s1 = set()
for i in range(len(file1)):
    s1.add( ( a1[i], b1[i], c1[i], d1[I] ) )
for j in range(len(file2)):
    if ( a2[j], b2[j], c2[j], d2[j] ) in s1:
        perform something
```

Comment: Note that sets cannot contain lists. Use tuples instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), to merge those nested loops into one loop. It will still be a loop, but a bit nicer.

```py
for (i, j) in itertools.product(range(len(file1)), range(len(file2))):  
    if a1[i] == a2[j] and b1[i]==b2[j] and c1[i]==c2[j] and d1[i]==d2[j]:
        #some calculations stored and returned
```